# logic with bool

Tags: c#

I have this logic in my analysis file. 
The user has the option to choose a input file. if an error occurs or if the user has a invalid entry in the input file, then the logic checks and prints the error.

This method returns a bool success. Depending on if all the input is valid, successtakes T/F.
If success = T, then the next step analyzing the input starts. 
Now here's my question. How do i return a false`
;

```
if (xxx > 100)
{
    errMsg = "Number of xxx should be <= 100";
    swRpt.WriteLine(errTitle + errMsg);
}
// sizing
;
swRpt.WriteLine("   Epsilon");

//Repair
success = Numerical.Check("repair", inputs.repair.ToString(), 
                          out dtester, out errMsg);
if (!success)
{
    swRpt.WriteLine(errTitle + errMsg);
}
success = Numerical.Check("prob", inputs.prob.ToString(), 
                          out dtester, out errMsg);
if (!success)
{
    swRpt.WriteLine(errTitle + errMsg);
}
```

so now finally

```
if (success)
{
   //run the analysis method
}
if(!success)
{
   exit 
}
```

I need to exit if even one input is wrong. the first could be wrong and the last one could be a correct input value.

Comment: Can you show the real program instead of this pseudo code?

Comment: Exit from what?  A method or the program?

Comment: I dont think so. I can explain if the question is not very clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another status flag that will be updated to false anytime there is a failure:

```
bool status = true;
if (xxx > 100)
{ 
    errMsg = "Number of xxx should be <= 100";
    swRpt.WriteLine(errTitle + errMsg);
    status = false;
}
// sizing

swRpt.WriteLine("   Epsilon");

//Repair
success = Numerical.Check("repair", inputs.repair.ToString(), 
                          out dtester, out errMsg);
if (!success)
{
    swRpt.WriteLine(errTitle + errMsg);
    status = false;
}
success = Numerical.Check("prob", inputs.prob.ToString(), 
                          out dtester, out errMsg);
if (!success)
{
    swRpt.WriteLine(errTitle + errMsg);
    status = false;
}

return status;
```